# Where does Webform store the YAML form design data?

Tags: webforms

I have looked in the database and can see the `form_submission_data` table but the actual form design (field names and datatypes) I can't locate.
I know you can access this from the front end but I want to re-create forms from a previous version.
This is for a new Drupal8 site migration from Dr7.

Comment: D8 configuration is stored in a .yml **file**, not in the DB.

Comment: Where would I find them then? I looked in the file system but there was no obvious location.

Comment: It’s in the database in one of the config tables. It will only be in yml if you’ve exported the site configuration to yml (at which point you’d probably know where it is). If you run `drush cex`, you’ll find the form called `webform.foo` in the resulting yml

Comment: I believe you'll want to enable webform UI and then once you do that, you can access the form design as YAML.

Comment: I can see exporting config comes under "Development -> Configuration synchronization" in Drupal 8 but I cannot find that feature in Drupal 7. Made a back up of the Drupal 7 site which is hosted elsewhere previously so I have access to the old forms layout at least.
I'm happy to rebuild them manually as there aren't that many.